# can anyone explain why train and test data encoded differently?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

I'm new and started learning, so would expect someone to explain me the question.
I'm following this [sagemaker_clarify_bias_explain](https://github.com/aws/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/main/sagemaker-clarify/fairness_and_explainability/fairness_and_explainability_boto3.ipynb)
Is there any reason why training and test feature are different here?
What I mean in training Target as a column exists while in Test this column doesn't exists. Why this is ? is this intentional ? This block is from `Encode and Upload the Dataset`

```
from sklearn import preprocessing


def number_encode_features(df):
    result = df.copy()
    encoders = {}
    for column in result.columns:
        if result.dtypes[column] == np.object:
            encoders[column] = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
            result[column] = encoders[column].fit_transform(result[column].fillna("None"))
    return result, encoders


training_data = pd.concat([training_data["Target"], training_data.drop(["Target"], axis=1)], axis=1)
training_data, _ = number_encode_features(training_data)
training_data.to_csv("train_data.csv", index=False, header=False)

testing_data, _ = number_encode_features(testing_data)
test_features = testing_data.drop(["Target"], axis=1)
test_target = testing_data["Target"]
test_features.to_csv("test_features.csv", index=False, header=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

AWS's document ["XGBoost Algorithm" - "Input/Output Interface for the XGBoost Algorithm"](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/xgboost.html#InputOutput-XGBoost) has some information about the input data formats.

> For training with columnar input, the algorithm assumes that the target variable (label) is the first column. For inference, the algorithm assumes that the input has no label column.

Hope this answers your question.